# New browser window with information generated by Java applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a Java applet.

After user inputs data into the Java applet controls he presses button in Java applet and Java applet performs some calculating and result is a table (for simplicity table can be considered as `String[][]`).

I want to show new browser window and output this table in it as html `<table>`.
How can this be done?
Preferred way is to use javascript if needed, but not involving some server side handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, JavaScript will have to be used to open the window and populate the HTML - this is something the applet simply has no access to.

Luckily, JavaScript can easily call any public methods your Java applet provides. Unfortunately, Java cannot return a String[][] to JavaScript, but it CAN return a String.

So what you can do is have your Java applet return a JSON serialization of your String[][] array. JavaScript can then convert that JSON to a JavaScript array using the JSON.parse function (available on most modern browsers, but there are also libaries available at [json.org](http://json.org))

So here's an example of what I am talking about (that works with at least Java 5 and Chrome):

### The Applet Code

```
import java.applet.*;
public class Test extends Applet {
    String data[][];
    public void init() {
        data = new String[5][2];
        data[0] = new String[] { "Peter", "Griffin"};
        data[1] = new String[] { "Glen", "Quagmire"};
        data[2] = new String[] { "Joe", "Something"};
        data[3] = new String[] { "Cleveland", "Brown"};
        data[4] = new String[] { "Buzz", "Killington"};
    }

    public String getData() {
        return toJSON(data);
    }

    /* Quick and dirty, you may want to look
    * online for a 'complete' converter
    *
    * This returns [["Peter", "Griffin"], ["Glen", "Quagmire"], ... etc
    */
    protected String toJSON(String data[][]) {
        int x, y;
        String s = "[";
        for (y = 0;y < data.length;y += 1) {
            s += "[";
            for (x = 0;x < data[y].length;x += 1) {
                s += "\""+data[y][x].replaceAll("\"","\\\"")+"\"";
                if (x < data[y].length-1) {
                    s += ", ";
                }
            }
            s += "]";
            if (y < data.length-1) {
                s += ", ";
            }
        }
        s += "]";

        return s;
    }
}
```

### The JavaScript Code

```
<html>
<body>
<p><applet id="applet" code="Test"></applet></p>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Click me"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var button = document.getElementById("button"), applet = document.getElementById("applet");
    button.onclick = function () {
        var html = [], newWindow, data = JSON.parse(applet.getData()), j;

        html.push("<table><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>");
        for (j = 0;j < data.length;j += 1) {
            html.push("<tr><td>"+data[j][0]+"</td><td>"+data[j][1]+"</td></tr>");
        }
        html.push("</table>");

        newWindow = window.open();
        newWindow.document.firstChild.innerHTML = html.join("");
    };
}());
</script>
```

Let me know if you need further clarification!

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot! I will try it later.
Actually it is enough for me for now to know how to output string, not a table - I would like to understand how java and java-script should communicate. But for table it is even better.

Comment: I see in your code the button is created in java-script. But I have button in applet (I just updated question). Is it possible to adjust the code to account this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a little trickier and I'm afraid I've never actually done that. However, I can tell you that you must use the LiveConnect API's JSObject, and this specific section in Sun's documentation will tell you how: https://jdk6.dev.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/#JAVA_TO_JS

Comment: @Matt your last link helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Preferred way is to use javascript if needed, but not involving some server side handling.

If you really must not have any server side interaction, it'll have to be a jQuery hide/show situation.

If you can bear some server side work, do it with an applet collaborating with  servlet.  The applet won't do the calculation; the servlet will.  After it's complete, the servlet adds the result to the output page and redirects the output stream to it.